# Scanner will not wait for user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, wait

I am having trouble making my scanner wait for user input. My issue is in these lines of code: 
`System.out.println("Enter the day of the month: ");
        newOnetime.setDay(scan.nextInt());
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the year: ");
        newOnetime.setYear(scan.nextInt());`

I cannot get the user to input the year because the scanner just jumps over it. This is what my console output looks like from my debugging:

Press 1 for new one time appointment (assume I press 1)

Enter a description of the appointment: 
dentist visit

Enter the month of your appointment: 
3

Enter the day of the month:

Enter the year:

^^ right there the user cant put in the year because the console assumes the number applies to both day and year.

I apologize if this is an easy fix. I am not the biggest fan of scanners and usually I get tripped up by little nuances. Thanks!

---

Here is the Driver for my program: 
    package appointmentBook;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import Appointment.Appointment;
import Appointment.Daily;
import Appointment.Monthly;
import Appointment.Onetime;

public class AppointmentBookDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press 1 for new one time appointment");
        Onetime.createOneTime(scan);
}
```

And this is the Onetime Class:
    package Appointment;

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Onetime extends Appointment{
    public Onetime(String description, int month, int day, int year) {
         super(description, month, day, year);

    }
/**
 * this method creates a new onetime appt. I realize it is a lengthy
 * method but it is necessary and I couldn't logically break it into
 * smaller methods. 
 * @param scan the scanner that is passed from the driver class
 */
public static void createOneTime(Scanner scan) {
    Onetime newOnetime = new Onetime(null, 0, 0, 0);

    System.out.println("Enter a description of the appointment: ");
    newOnetime.setDescription(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Enter the month of your appointment: ");
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int month = 0;
        if (month > 0 && month < 13) {
        month = scan.nextInt();
        }
    } else if (scan.hasNextLine()){
        String monthString = scan.next().toLowerCase();
        switch (monthString) {
        case "january": newOnetime.setMonth(1); break;
        case "february": newOnetime.setMonth(2); break;
        case "march": newOnetime.setMonth(3); break;
        case "april": newOnetime.setMonth(4); break;
        case "may": newOnetime.setMonth(5); break;
        case "june": newOnetime.setMonth(6); break;
        case "july": newOnetime.setMonth(7); break;
        case "august": newOnetime.setMonth(8); break;
        case "september": newOnetime.setMonth(9); break;
        case "october": newOnetime.setMonth(10); break;
        case "november": newOnetime.setMonth(11); break;
        case "december": newOnetime.setMonth(12); break;
        default: 
        {System.out.println("Please enter an integer representing a month...");
        newOnetime.setMonth(scan.nextInt());
        }
        }
     }
    System.out.println("Enter the day of the month: ");
    newOnetime.setDay(scan.nextInt());
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the year: ");
    newOnetime.setYear(scan.nextInt());
    scan.nextLine();
}
```

}

Comment: Also I tried consuming the newline char during debugging and that produced no results, that is why there is the random scan.nextLine(); in there.

Comment: Please add enough relevant code

Comment: what else do you need to see @AnttiHaapala ? i figured this might be enough but I can post the class definitions and other code.

Comment: The code just before; the one that reads the month of appointment...

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is that this just works fine for me:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the day of the month: ");
        System.out.println("You typed: " + scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter the year: ");
        System.out.println("You typed: " + scan.nextInt());
    }
}
```

The `Scanner` blocks every time and waits for input from `System.in`.

Comment: see that's what I thought, not sure if you've seen my edit yet but I have a hunch that this problem arises from my default clause in the switch statement.. thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to do away with my switch statement and just force the user input to be number from 1-12 inclusive only. Doing this allows me to stay on top of user input and I don't have to worry about a messy slow switch. Thanks for input but I have decided to design the program differently! Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.